# How to use the random function in j2me

Tags: java-me

i'm using j2me to create a question/answer game but I don't know how to randomly choose questions I have created as methods to display please I need help on this. Thanks!

```
public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {

if(c==proceed){

int n = 0;

Random r = new Random();

while(n<2){

int i = r.nextInt(36);

n++;

}

 display.setCurrent(getform23());

}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Random like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int number = rnd.nextInt(36);
```

What you do with that number depends on what you want to achieve (cant't figure that out with the available info on your question now).

Regards.